# Я должен решить задачу, но не могу понять ее условие

Tags: java, бинарное-дерево, дерево

Мне нужно решить эту задачу:
(*)В двоичном дереве найти все одинаковые (по значениям, но различные) пары поддеревьев. Вернуть в виде списка пар узлов.

Который час не могу разобраться с этим условием . Объясните мне, пожалуйста, на примере дерева.

Comment: В дереве каждый узел - вершина какого то поддерева. Вам надо найти такие узлы, которые являются вершинами одинаковых поддеревьев.

Comment: Если вам дать пару деревьев, вы сможете сказать равны ли эти деревья. Если вам дать одно дерево, то вы сможете перечислить все его поддеревья. Внимание вопрос: есть ли среди поддеревьев данного дерева равные? Какой часть вам не понятна?

Comment: Так все просто?  Формулировка задания меня вводила в ступор. А вы расписали все очень понятно. Спасибо!

Comment: формулировка условия реально ужасное